# Does CosmosDB's Mongo API support the full BSON spec?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Particularly, Binary data? CosmosDB's Core SQL/Document API supports JSON, which does not allow binary data on the wire easily.

Answer (score 1):

As i read, Support is Minimal. From the [`docs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/faq),

> Some of Azure Cosmos DB's internal formats for encoding information,
>   such as binary fields, are currently not as efficient as one might
>   like. Therefore this can cause unexpected limitations on data size.
>   For example, currently one couldn't use the full one Meg of a table
>   entity to store binary data because the encoding increases the data's
>   size